# angular primeng dynamic columns

Tags: angular, primeng, dynamic-tables

I have a problem getting data for my dynamic columns with primeNg. I have following JSON structure:

[image]

My Component.ts looks like this:

```
this.claimOverviewService.getCarClaimOverview(this.domain).then(claimOverview => {
  this.carClaimOverview = claimOverview;
  //console.log(this.carClaimOverview);
});

this.cols = [
  {field: 'id', header: 'VorgangsId', type: 'string'},
  {field: 'repairCosts', header: 'Reparaturkosten', type: 'number'},
  {field: 'status.name', header: 'Status', type: 'status'},
  {field: 'creationDate', header: 'Eingang', type: 'date'}
];
```

And my Componjent.html looks like this:

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="carClaimOverview" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
      {{col.header}}
      <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-claim let-columns="columns">
  <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      <span *ngIf="col.type !== 'date'">
        {{claim[col.field]}}
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="col.type === 'date'">
        {{claim[col.field] | date:'fullDate'}}
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

My Datatable looks like this:
[image]
As you can see the column status is not displayed. My cols array got a field 'status.name', but the name does not appear. If i put status into the field i get [object Object] in my datatable. 
[image]

So the field does not detect sub objects of my json. Is there a possibility to show my sub objects or letting field know that there are object lying under?

Comment: Can you try putting `status[name]` as the column field.

Comment: Does not work .

Comment: Try doing status[0].name

Comment: Also, can you out a console.log(this.carClaimOverview[0].status) and console.log(this.carClaimOverview[0].status.name. I am guessing you are getting an array of objects in your status field. I could be wrong.

Comment: At first this does not work. Additionally there is to say, that when you do array[0] you don't get an array of objects but ONE object, the first of the array. If i type this.carClaimOverview[0].status i get the status json object of the first claim object. It is not null. There are information inside. But the field does not recognize the sub object. i can pu status inside, but the datatable will render [Object.object].

Comment: NICE! This is working very well :) Thank you Sanoj_V. Maybe you put an answer to this post so i can mark it to the right answer.

Comment: @AntonStyopin I have posted an answer with less description if you want to add more description then you can add and accept it as answer ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the field to `claim[col.field]?.name`.

Replace `cols` of object from

```
 {field: 'status.name', header: 'Status', type: 'status'},
```

to this

```
 `{field: 'status', header: 'Status', type: 'status'},`
```

Comment: can you please explain the `claim[col.field]?.name`

Comment: @AbduManaz obviously object doesn't bind in html dom you need to specify the key static or dynamic. In this case `claim[col.field]` ie `claim[status]` that contains a object and that always shows you `[object Object]`. Here you need to specify the key like i had done this.

Comment: Ok. I understood that, but what I didnt understand is the `?` symbol and the use of `.name` outside of the square brackets. Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: @AbduManaz this will check `status` object have key `name` or not. this `?` only handle error in html page when your data is asyncronous.